# Can I extract 3d models from RobotStudio?

Tags: ros, ros-melodic, abb

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

I need to make a ROS package for an ABB IRB 6640-235/2.55
Does anyone know if I can extract the dae and stl files for the 3d models from RobotStudio? Or does anyone have a suggestion where i could get these files from?

thanks,
Dominik

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/376461/can-i-extract-3d-models-from-robotstudio?/) by [Dominik JBS](https://answers.ros.org/users/68781/dominik-jbs/) on ROS Answers with karma: 7 on 2021-04-19

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [stokesaphone](https://answers.ros.org/users/154255/stokesaphone/) on 2023-06-15**:
Hi, I am working to create an ABB IRB 2600 12kg/1.85m urdf. I have found the CAD from abb online and when importing into meshlab the robot will self assemble. I had to downscale the robot for RViz as the scales were different. When I open the urdf in RViz my robot does not self assemble as in meshlab. I have tried two things: leaving origins for joints 0,0,0 and then also closely matching to the urdf for the 2600 1.65m variant. (the only difference is length of upright arm). Any recommendations for fixing?

Thanks, Ryan!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

> Does anyone know if I can extract the dae and stl files for the 3d models from RobotStudio?

I don't know about RobotStudio, but ABB distributes CAD models for "all" of their robots via their site.

I believe [IRB 6640 CAD Models](https://new.abb.com/products/robotics/industrial-robots/irb-6640/irb-6640-cad) should have the files for the specific variant you're after.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2021-04-19

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2021-04-19**:
And if you model that variant, a PR to add it to [ros-industrial/abb/abb_irb6640_support](https://github.com/ros-industrial/abb/tree/dcb72869f722f7eac2be3c536f4af0ee776d131b/abb_irb6640_support) would be a great contribution.

**Comment by [Dominik JBS](https://answers.ros.org/users/68781/dominik-jbs/) on 2021-04-21**:
Thanks for the help. Will definitely do a PR once I've finished and tested it.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2021-08-07**:
The new #q383955 seems to suggest you succeeded in creating the support files for your robot variant?